# Missing closing parenthesis in kendo React

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I have a React app. If I want to build this I get an error

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css
ParserError: Expected closing parenthesis at line: 1, column 5

however, when i check all.css it looks ok.

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

\node_modules@progress\kendo-theme-default\dist\all.scss

```
.k-scrollview-view {
            width: calc( 100% / var(--kendo-scrollview-views, 1) );
            // flex: 0 0 calc( 100% / var(--kendo-scrollview-views, 1) );  }
```

comment this line.

Comment: For the error in the OP which mentions the .css (not .scss) file, commenting out the same line worked for me: 
.k-scrollview-wrap.k-scrollview-animate .k-scrollview-view {
    width: calc(100%/var(--kendo-scrollview-views, 1));
    /* flex: 0 0 calc(100%/var(--kendo-scrollview-views, 1)); */
}